.Net 7 Schedule task for send mail with attachment
In my .NET 7 web application, I need to send emails with attachments upon user submission. Occasionally, this process might take longer than expected. To avoid making users wait, I'm considering implementing a scheduled task for the email sending process.
I'm wondering if utilizing the built-in .NET 7 scheduler could potentially cause performance issues. What alternatives might offer better performance and reliability for this task?

You can opt to use Hangfire to run scheduled jobs
